# <soap:address location="??????????????" /> WSDL address location

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

```
<service name="MathServicesService">
    <port name="MathServicesPort" binding="tns:MathServicesPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost/C:\Users\cvolkernick\workspace\WSDLServer\bin\math\"/>
    </port>
  </service>
```

What should I have where it says `<soap:address location="URL" />` ?? I am trying to test my web service locally with Web Services Explorer, but I keep getting 404s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the service locally you *must* have a server running (for example a Tomcat application server or even a simple JAX-WS endpoint).

Then you need to specify the URL of the endpoint here (or as a parameter when you get the service instance).

Comment: Do I need to convert my project to an dynamic web app in order to deploy it on glassfish?